# Failed to check the values has addslashes values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have stored the datas in db with the addslashes when i submit the form.

Im stored values using the function like below

```
addslashes(trim($data[1]));
```

I want to check existing record in that table but its not working when it has value like

> Regional Sales Director - Americas\'

Its checking existing values in table without those shlashes

> \'

My query is

```
$query = $this->db->query("select * from tbl_contacts where contact_name='".$name."' and contact_company='".$company."' and contact_designation='".$designation."'");
$result1 = $query->result();
```

Comment: Could you use stripslashes to fix your data?

Comment: Otherwise use prepared statements with addslashes on your lookup values, but that feels rather icky.

Comment: How did you originally insert the data?

Comment: addslashes(trim($data[1])); By using this function

Comment: addslashes doesn't magically insert data into databases.  Did you do this via code igniter?  If so what version?  Did you use code igniter's query bindings?  Or did you use one of their db escape methods?  And if so why did you escape with addslashes?

Comment: U want to see the code

Comment: your code is just wide open for sql injection. also what exactly is going on? i can't understand what you expect should happen

Comment: @Vinothini I will sort out the issue for you. Just want more clarification that your search results are not coming due to single quote ' in your data.

Comment: Your query is also quite specific, perhaps you need to use ORs instead of ANDs and/or even LIKEs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i should answer to this, but i feel i should because what you are doing is wrong in so many ways...

You should never ever do things like that if you want to insert data - especially if you use a framework which can do the job for you...

First of all you've to understand how Codeigniter inserts Data

### Use the query builder

an example for inserting data would be

```
$arrData = [
    'contact_name' => $this->input->post('contact_name'),
    'contact_company' => $this->input->post('contact_company')
];

$this->db->insert('tbl_contacts', $arrData);
```

> please read carefully the section in the CI Documentation [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data)

and your select query is a disaster because you don't protect anything - you are widely open to any sort of attacks as Alex already said in the comments

Instead you should try the following:

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select('*')
    ->from('tbl_contacts')
    ->where('contact_name', $name)
    ->where('conatct_company', $company)
    ->where('contact_designation', $designation)
    ->get();

$result1 = $query->result();
```

Furthermore, please study the documentation, below are some links which are mandatory

1. [Form Validation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html)
2. [Security Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html)
3. [Input Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html)
4. [Query Builder Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)

Comment: But i didnt used form to save datas in db Its a csv file uploading

Answer (score 0):

If you've accidentally escaped your data with addslashes on top of existing database escaping:  you may be able to methodically remove those back slashes with an update and replace to fix your data.

```
UPDATE tableName
SET    columnName = replace(columnName, '\\', '');
```

But do be very careful, back up all your data first and test on a sample.

Then in the future, do not use addslashes on top of your database library's escape mechanism for updates or inserts.